# Does the Last Login Date become blank after a user hasn't logged in for 6 months?

Tags: user-management, login

Two part question here actually.

1. Does the Last Login Date standard Salesforce field become blank if the user hasn't logged in for 6 months? Salesforce only retains login records for 6 months but I wonder if it the value gets cleared after that time is up. We are trying to assess some integration user accounts that have a blank Last Login Date value.
2. I think I know the answer to this, but I wanted to get clarification about if API and integration logins trigger the Last Login Date to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last Login is NOT cleared after 6 months. It shows just fine.

- My example I was going to show last logged in 7/2016

As for updating the last login, yes, if the user logs in via API it does update the login

- Login Type will be "Other Apex API" or similar

Tried to upload an image to show it but seems the uploader is broken